# How can i make my javascript code add the total amount

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so i have been working on this code that allows the user to select different radio button options and then gives them the total cost after they select them.

This is what i have tried: (html)

```
 Total <input type="text" id="count" value="$0" readonly />       


<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<h4>Contact plugin</h4>
<input type="radio" name="pak1" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="4&#x00A;Qty" onClick="changeText(0)">No

<input type="radio"  class="mnozstvi_sleva" onclick="changeText(5)" value="2&#x00A;Qty" name="PAk1" >Yes!

<h4> Mailing list</h4> <input type="radio"  class="mnozstvi_sleva" onclick="changeText2(0)" value="2&#x00A;Qty" name="PAk21" >No

  <input type="radio"  class="mnozstvi_sleva" onclick="changeText2(10)" value="2&#x00A;Qty" name="PAk21" >Yes
        `
```

(javascript)

```
function changeText(value) {
 document.getElementById('count').value = 10 * value;   
}

function changeText2(value) {
 document.getElementById('count').value = 10 * value;   
}
```

So i need this to add together instead of change to one number you can run the code here on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/573/)

Comment: just use `changeText(...)`. the second one is unnecessary

Comment: I suggest another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess you need to use handlers for two radios. You are using only for the `Yes` and nothing for the other. Try something like this:

```js
function updateTotal () {
  total = 0;
  total += frm.contact_plugin.value * 10 + frm.mailing_list.value * 10;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
form ul, form ul li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
form ul li strong, form ul li label {display: inline-block; width: 120px; padding: 3px;}
form ul li label {width: 75px;}
```

```html
<p><strong>Billing</strong></p>
<form action="" id="frm">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>Contact plugin</strong>
      <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="contact_plugin" onclick="updateTotal()" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="contact_plugin" onclick="updateTotal()" /> No</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Mailing list</strong>
      <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="mailing_list" onclick="updateTotal()" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="mailing_list" onclick="updateTotal()" /> No</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<p><strong>Total:</strong> <span id="total">0</span>$</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
var cost1 = 0, cost2 = 0;
function changeText(value) {
 cost1 = 10 * value;   
calculateSum();
}

function changeText2(value) {
 cost2 = 10 * value;   
calculateSum();
}

function calculateSum() {
document.getElementById('count').value = cost1 + cost2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest more dynamic way: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sherali/f78pxa6s/)**

You should call below method like `changeTotal(100, this.name)`. It doesn't depend parent, so, you can use everywhere, with any tags(not only input) through event

```
var groups = {};
function changeTotal(value, group) {
    groups[group.toLowerCase()] = value;//toLowerCase has added for  PAk1 and pak1
    var sum = 0;

    Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (key) {
        sum += groups[key]
    });
    document.getElementById('count').value = "$"+(10 * sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateTotal () {
  total = 0;
  total += frm.contact_plugin.value * 10 + frm.mailing_list.value * 10;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
form ul, form ul li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
form ul li strong, form ul li label {display: inline-block; width: 120px; padding: 3px;}
form ul li label {width: 75px;}
```

```html
<p><strong>Billing</strong></p>
<form action="" id="frm">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>Contact plugin</strong>
      <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="contact_plugin" onclick="updateTotal()" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="contact_plugin" onclick="updateTotal()" /> No</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Mailing list</strong>
      <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="mailing_list" onclick="updateTotal()" /> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="mailing_list" onclick="updateTotal()" /> No</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<p><strong>Total:</strong> <span id="total">0</span>$</p>
```